# Python Pandas columns.get_loc with itertuples

Tags: python, pandas

In the following code, I'm trying to simply print 1 when a positive value is found in column 'value'. 
But, I get an erorr "TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'Timestamp' and 'int'". 
This is because there is an index column in the row object.
Where df.columns.get_loc("value 1 ~~") returns 1 for df which is correct but not correct column index for row object.
So, what is the correct syntax for doing this?

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

# Sample data
data = {    
    'datetime': [
        datetime(2023, 11, 11, 8, 0, 0),
        datetime(2023, 11, 11, 8, 5, 0),
        datetime(2023, 11, 11, 8, 10, 0),
        datetime(2023, 11, 11, 8, 15, 0),
        datetime(2023, 11, 11, 8, 20, 0),
        datetime(2023, 11, 11, 8, 25, 0),
        datetime(2023, 11, 11, 8, 30, 0),
        datetime(2023, 11, 11, 8, 35, 0),
        datetime(2023, 11, 11, 8, 40, 0),
        datetime(2023, 11, 11, 8, 45, 0),
        datetime(2023, 11, 11, 8, 50, 0),
    ],
    'value 1 ~~': [1,  3, 1, 0, -1, 1, 0, 2, -3, 0, -3],                   
}

# Create the DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

for row in df.itertuples(index=True):

    print(row.Index)    
    if row[df.columns.get_loc("value 1 ~~")] >= 0:
        print(1)
```

Note:
I don't want to do

```
if row[df.columns.get_loc("value 1 ~~")+1] >= 0:
```

**Update 2023/12/15 15:20** 
row._ _ *getattribute* _ _("value 1 ~~") doesn't work either.

Comment: the actual column name is more nasty like "a nasty col name ~~" that I can't use .

Comment: Weird, seems pandas renames the column to something usable. If you just `print(row)` in your for loop you will see it. Anyway, for your sample data, you  can use `row._2`

Comment: row._2 is something I also want to avoid. Because in my program there are more columns and the column I'd like to access changes from time to time.

Comment: I've reopened the question. Can you not just use boolean indexing e.g. `df[df['value 1 ~~'] >= 0]` though?

Comment: Since the actual dataframe's records are huge, I need an efficient way accessing a column's value in an itertuples loop.

Comment: it would be simpler to rename column to `value1` and later use `row.value1`

Comment: problem is that it uses `collections.nametuple(..., rename=True)` and it doesn't have information about original name `"value 1 ~~"` and you can't get its position. If you don't want to change column's name then you should calculate `index = df.columns.get_loc("value 1 ~~")+1` before loop, and use `row[index]` inside loop. BTW: source code for [itertuples](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v2.1.4/pandas/core/frame.py#L1455-L15370)

Comment: Indeed, from the source: "The column names will be renamed to positional names if they are *invalid Python identifiers*, repeated, or start with an underscore.". Do you have to use `itertuples`? What about using `iterrows` i.e. `for i, row in df.iterrows()` instead, then you can just access `row['value 1 ~~']`

Answer (score 0):

You are indexing the `row`, which includes the index of `df` as a column, with the location of the column in the `df`, which does not include the index as a column. Hence:

the col-index 0 in the `row` represents the index col in `df`

the col-index 1 in the `row` represents the datetime col in `df`

the col-index 2 in the `row` represents the value ~~1 col in `df`

If value ~~ 1 is always your last column, then something like this might be a quick solution:

```
for row in df.itertuples(index=True): 
    if row[-1] >= 0:
        print(1)
```

As others have suggested, it's much better to change the code to either `iterrows` while also changing the column name because the interpreter does not like `value ~~1`